# Is Differentiability a subset of continuity

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, derivatives, continuity

This question is a nooby one, but suppose I had a discontinuous function $f(x) \in (-\infty, +\infty)$, where
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
    x^2,& \text{if } x \in (-\infty, 2)\\
    x^2 + 3,& \text{if } x \in [2, +\infty)
\end{cases}
$$
Of course the function isn't continuous at $x=2$, since
$$\lim_{x \to 2^-}f(x) = 4 \neq \lim_{x \to 2^+}f(x) = 7$$
But,
$$
f^{'}(2^-) = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0^-}\frac{(2+\Delta x)^2 - 2^2}{\Delta x} = f^{'}(2^+) = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0^+}\frac{(2 + \Delta x)^2 + 3 -(2^2 + 3)}{\Delta x} = 4
$$
Does that mean that the function is differentiable at $x=2$, though not continuous? Or is differentiability a strict subset of continuity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a proof that differentiability is a subset of continuity (In fact a strict one, since there are plenty examples of continuous functions but not differentiable).

Consider a differentiable function $f:A\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, where $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ and further choose a point $x_0$ in the interior of $A$.

Then by the definition of the derivative, we have that the limit as $x$ goes to $x_0$ of $\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}$ exists, and is equal to $f'(x_0)$.
Namely:

$$f'(x_0)=\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow x_0}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}$$
Now, consider the function:
$$g(x)=\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}$$

We can rewrite the above as:

$$f(x)-f(x_0)=(x-x_0)g(x)\Rightarrow f(x)=(x-x_0)g(x)+f(x_0)$$
$$\Rightarrow\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow x_0}f(x)=\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow x_0}\left((x-x_0)g(x)+f(x_0)\right)$$

But, we know from the definition of $g$, that $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow x_0}g(x)$ exists and: $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow x_0}g(x)=f'(x_0)$

Hence, we get that:

$$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow x_0}f(x)=\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow x_0}\left((x-x_0)g(x)+f(x_0)\right) = (x_0-x_0)f'(x_0)+f(x_0)=f(x_0)$$
$$\Rightarrow \lim\limits_{x\rightarrow x_0}f(x)=f(x_0)$$
which is exactly the definition of $f$ being continuous at $x_0$.

With a similar argument for points at the boundary of $A$ using left and right limits, together with the fact that the point we picked is "arbitrary" (I'm putting the word arbitrary in "" because in a sense we differentiated between the interior points and the boundary points), you can conclude that $f$ is continuous on $A$, so you get:

$$f\text{ differentiable on $A$}\Rightarrow f\text{ continuous on $A$}$$

Answer (score 1):

As you defined it, $f(2)=7$. So the definition of $f^{'}(2^-)$ is $\lim_{\Delta x \to 0^-}\frac{(2+\Delta x)^2 - 7^2}{\Delta x}$, and not what you wrote. Since that limit diverges, $f$ is not differentiable at $x=2$.

As for your last question, if a function is differentiable at some point, it's also continuous at that point. Hence, the differentiability set of a function is always a subset of its continuity set. However, it does not have to be a strict subset.